# MySql now() in java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm wondering, how can I execute a MYsQL Command like `select id, name, date from table where date > now()`? I'm trying to retrieve the data, but when I use this command in my Java class I get nothing back..

Comment: Assuming your code doesn't have the typos in your question, that is you meant "select id, name, date FROM table WHERE date > now()". Are you using JDBC?

Comment: Maybe there are no matching records to return?  Maybe the code is producing an error and you're simply ignoring it?  We can't know unless you provide at least *some* information.

Comment: Already edited.. Typing mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
Select id, name, date from table where date > now()
```